# how to type extended class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a set of classes extending a base class. And there is a function which might be called with an argument as any of the classes above. How do I type the function here?

For example:

```
class BaseClass {}

class A extends BaseClass {
// ...
}

class B extends BaseClass{
}
```

and here is the function I want to type:

```
function myfunc(arg){
 // do something
}
```

here the arg will be A or B or anything which is extended from BaseClass.
(I don't prefer giving It as `A | B`, because there is a lot of classes and it is a generic function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote "it is a generic function". So give it a generic type argument with a constraint to extend `BaseClass`

```
function myfunc<T extends BaseClass>(arg: T){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was writing it wrongly like `myfunc<T>(arg:  T extends BaseClass>` . Your answer solved It for me